# Large dimensions image cannot be displayed in bitmapimage in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, bitmapimage

I need show 2,54MB jpeg image (15232 x 7912 pixels, 96DPI) in Silverlight 5.0.

I using BitMapImage component and image not showing. 
When opening a browser window by doubleclick on image, will sometimes appear.

When i have breakpoint in ImageFailed handler i see in eventargs ErrorException: "AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR" (InnerException is null).

What does it mean?

Thanks and sorry for my english.
Code below.

```
    string url = await GetDocumentURLAsync(...);
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(url);
    image.Source = bitmapImage;

    image.ImageFailed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorException);
    };
```

Comment: Maybe the resolution is too big for Silverlight. Can you try with smaller resolution?